# Translate big text i18n

Tags: json, typescript, ionic-framework, internationalization, translate

I want to translate a large text in i18n and I want to organize it in several lines, but I do not know how. Example:

Now:

"Bboying": "Breakdance, también llamado break o b-boying / b-girling"

I would like that:

"Bboying": `Breakdance, también llamado 
            break o b-boying / b-girling`

Thanks in advance

Comment: do you just want to store it on multiple lines? or display it on multiple lines?

Comment: Show it in multiple lines, to organize better. If it were a single line, it would be huge.

Comment: and for some reason you don't want to turn on line wrap in your editor?